# Existence of a continuous function with zeros in a closed set

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

If $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ is a closed subset show that there is a continuous real-valued function on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = 0$ if and only if $x \in E$.

I've considered trying to show that the preimage of any open or closed set in $\mathbb{R}$ must be open or closed, but this didn't seem to get me anywhere.

Comment: The preimage of what?

Answer (score 3):

$f(x) = \min[\text{dist}(x,E),1]$, where $\text{dist}(x,E)=\inf\{|x-y|:y\in E\}$

Based on comments, we could also more simply use

$g(x) =\inf\{|x-y|:y\in E\}$

Comment: +1 Why not just the distance?

Comment: +1: but I suspect the OP won't know what $\mbox{dist}(x, E)$ means.

Comment: I think I unconsciously added bounded as a condition when I read the question

Comment: More interestingly, you can arrange for $f$ to be $C^\infty$.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I actually had the graph of this function in mind when trying to intuitively think about this problem, but couldn't think of a way to mathematically describe it.

Comment: How would one rigorously prove that this is continuous?

Comment: $\epsilon-\delta$. Use the fact that the infimum is actually attained, together with the reverse triangle inequality. Also break up limits from the left and from the right.